# Method that returns current state name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there any method of `$state` that returns current state name ?

I want to know in controller the current state name.

What I am trying to do is `console.log($state.name);`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
console.log($state.current.name);
```